# Sending array of objects using java mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

```
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class SendMailTLS extends Customer{






public SendMailTLS (){
   Customer customer = new Customer();
   //firstName = customer.getFirstName();
  // email = customer.getEmail();

}

public static void main(String[] args){
     final String username = "MCVJ.PizzaOrdering@gmail.com";
     final String password = "";

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));


    String email = "";
    String firstName = "Joe";
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("MCVJ.PizzaOrdering@gmail.com")); // same email id
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("" + email + ""));// whome u have to send mails that person id
        message.setSubject("Thank You For Placing an Order with us! Below is your Order Receipt!");
        message.setText("..........."+ "\n"+
                dateFormat.format((date)) + "\n" +
                "............." + "\n" +
                "Dear "+ firstName  +" ,Below is your order receipt " + "\n"+

                "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

}

I have an arrayList of objects called orders[] that holds the customer's order( quantity, order name, and price). after the order is complete, i would like to send the customer a emailed receipt of his/her order. the problem is i dont know how to send an array using the .setText() in javaMail API.

Answer (score 0):

You can set mapping as you want. For example override toString in ArrayList, and show it as you want or use json library, to generate string json from arrayList.
So, you will get human readable text from your arrayList and put this text in setText() and send.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. so using the json library it would be something like String json = new Gson().toJson(name of the arrayList); ?

Comment: Yes, but don't forget to set rules for your custom type for serialization, if you are using one (List<YourType> list)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send the Order Details to a user then I think it should be in a proper human readable format. You can try something like below:

Considering you have `Order` class like this, You can override its `toString()` method to convert your order details into `String`

```
public class Order {

    private long id;
    private String productName;
    private int quantity;
    private double price;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Order [id=" + id + ", productName=" + productName + ", quantity=" + quantity + ", price=" + price + "]";
    }
}
```

And then in your sendEmail method you can use that `toString()` method.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    final String username = "MCVJ.PizzaOrdering@gmail.com";
    final String password = "";

   DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
   Date date = new Date();
   System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));


   String email = "";
   String firstName = "Joe";
   String content = "";
   List<Order> userOrders = null;
   Properties props = new Properties();
   props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
   props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
   props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
   props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

   Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
           new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
               protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                   return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
               }
           });

   try {

       Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
       message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("MCVJ.PizzaOrdering@gmail.com")); // same email id
       message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
               InternetAddress.parse("" + email + ""));// whome u have to send mails that person id
       message.setSubject("Thank You For Placing an Order with us! Below is your Order Receipt!");

       userOrders = databaseRepo.getUserOrders(userId); // You can replace this line however you are extracting user's data in your project

       content = "..........."+ "\n"+
            dateFormat.format((date)) + "\n" +
            "............." + "\n" +
            "Dear "+ firstName  +" ,Below is your order receipt " + "\n";

       for(Order order : userOrders){
            content += ""+order.toString()+"\n";
       }

       content += "\n\n No spam to my email, please!";

       message.setText(content);

       Transport.send(message);

       System.out.println("Done");

   } catch (MessagingException e) {
       throw new RuntimeException(e);
   }
}
```

Comment: userOrders is suppose to contain the customerID from the database ? i am using mySQL for the database. My Order class doesnt have a orderID. it looks like this                                                                       public Order(int _quantity, String _orderName, double _orderPrice){
        quantity = _quantity;
        orderName = _orderName;
        orderPrice = _orderPrice;
    }

Comment: I just gave an idea how you can write content in email. You can use your own already created models. But the Order table should have `userId` foreign key, this will help you to keep track of all user orders.